# ImageResizer - not resaving image if it's smaller than requested size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

OK, I am trying to use [ImageResizer component](http://imageresizing.net/) in my web app. I have following code:

```
var versions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
//Define the versions to generate
versions.Add("_001", "maxwidth=300&maxheight=300&format=jpg");
versions.Add("_002", "maxwidth=600&maxheight=600&format=jpg");
versions.Add("_003", "maxwidth=1920&maxheight=1080&format=jpg&process=no"); // I expect it not to resave the image if original is smaller

string uploadFolder = "...my folder path...";
if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(uploadFolder);

//Generate each version
foreach (string suffix in versions.Keys)
{
    //Generate a filename (GUIDs are best).
    string fileName = Path.Combine(uploadFolder, DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME + suffix);

    //Let the image builder add the correct extension based on the output file type
    fileName = ImageBuilder.Current.Build(file, fileName, new ResizeSettings(versions[suffix]), false, true);
}

file.SaveAs(uploadFolder + DEFAULT_IMAGE_NAME + "_000.jpg");
```

As you can tell I am saving 3 versions of one image + original image. However, I only want image to be re-encoded and re-saved if resizing is required. So if I upload 1000x1000 image I would expect that main_000.jpg and main_003.jpg are the same. However, that's not the case (ImageResizer resizes that image also, and often saved file size is bigger than main_000.jpg).

I tried adding process=no as parameter but it's not working. Anyone knows if this scenario is supported and which parameter I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//it may need to be improved
    Dictionary<string, SavingSettings> SaveVersions = new Dictionary<string, SavingSettings>();
    public void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        //set versions:
        SaveVersions.Add("xxl", new SavingSettings("xxl", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings())); //original size
        SaveVersions.Add("600px", new SavingSettings("600px", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(600, 600, ImageResizer.FitMode.Max, "jpg"))); //big
        SaveVersions.Add("80px", new SavingSettings("80px", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(80, 80, ImageResizer.FitMode.Max, "jpg"))); //80 px thumb
        SaveVersions.Add("260w", new SavingSettings("260w", new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings(260, 0, ImageResizer.FitMode.Max, "jpg"))); //260 px width thumb

    }

    public void SaveIt(string SourceFile,string TargetFileName) {
        using(System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.LoadImage(SourceFile, new ImageResizer.ResizeSettings())) {
            foreach(System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, SavingSettings> k in SaveVersions) {
                string TargetFilePath = Server.MapPath("../img/" + k.Value.VersionName + "/" + TargetFileName + ".jpg");
                string TargetFolder = Server.MapPath("../img/" + k.Value.VersionName);
                if(!System.IO.Directory.Exists(TargetFolder)) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(TargetFolder);
                if(bmp.Width > k.Value.ResizeSetting.Width || bmp.Height > k.Value.ResizeSetting.Height) {
                    //you may need to resize
                    ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(bmp, TargetFilePath, k.Value.ResizeSetting, false);
                } else {
                    //just copy it
                    //or in your example you can save uploaded file
                    System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFile, TargetFilePath);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct SavingSettings {
        public string VersionName;
        public ImageResizer.ResizeSettings ResizeSetting;
        public SavingSettings(string VersionName, ImageResizer.ResizeSettings ResizeSetting) {
            this.VersionName = VersionName;
            this.ResizeSetting = ResizeSetting;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### You need to use the URL API, not the Managed API, to perform dynamic image resizing.

Just get rid of the pre-resizing code, and save the upload to disk (make sure you sanitize the filename or use a GUID instead, however).

Then, use the URL API like this:

```
<img src="/uploads/original.jpg?maxwidth=300&maxheight=300&format=jpg" />
```

Comment: I save image to "guid-ed" directory so that's not an issue. I was thinking to pre-resize since I will be using images in Android app - so this scenario is not possible, only this resizing on the fly?

Comment: ImageResizer won't upscale images unless you tell it to, with &scale=both or &scale=canvas. So on tiny images, you're just telling it to save 4 copies of an image, while re-encoding 3 of them at 90% jpeg quality. 90% jpeg quality will produce large file sizes than the original if the original was saved at a lower quality setting.

Comment: Yeah - but can I tell ImageResizer "re-encode" ONLY if image is larger? Not "re-encode" always? And thanks for your help - I know this can be approached in different ways - I am just exploring options and want to learn more since I'm loving the library so far.

Comment: No such command exists in this version. user1942754 provided an excellent workaround, however.  **There are good reasons to always re-encode uploads, however. Many image formats (and many features of the JPEG and PNG formats) are not supported by browsers**. And most users believe that converting a file means renaming the extension, so... you can't really use that as any kind of indicator.

Comment: ICC profile normalization, format standardization, and metadata removal are a few things ImageResizer needs to do even if no resizing is performed.

Comment: Yeah - I know thing or two about image resizing so I know how I would check for images size + how it's safer to do that extra re-encoding (user uploads PNG with .jpg extension). Probably that suggestion from your answer is the best course of action - resizing images when user with certain resolution on their Android device wants to see the image. Anyways, I'll figure it out - thanks for providing me with options and thanks for the awesome library.